# Regexp: Trim parts of a string and return what ever is left

Tags: javascript, trim

Im trying to use regexp to get whatever's behind the # in my string "12344dfdfsss#isa", in this case I wanna get the 'isa' out of the string.

I found these answers ([How to remove a small part of the string in the big string using RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578821/how-to-remove-a-small-part-of-the-string-in-the-big-string-using-regexp)) helpful, but all it returns is 'true'.

```
var myString = '12344dfdfsss#isa',
    newRG = new RegExp('#(.*)$'),           
    trimmed = newTrim.test(myString);
```

I want it to retun 'isa' and not true.

Thanks for any help
// I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var trimmed = /#(.*)$/.exec('12344dfdfsss#isa')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use also use `match` to match a string against a regex, and then extract the first subexpression that matched using `[1]`:

```
var trimmed = '12344dfdfsss#isa'.match(/#(.*)$/)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's possible that the subject string could have more than one `#` then consider:

```
/#(.*)$/
```

captures everything that follows the *first* `#` in the subject string., while

```
/#(.*?)$/
```

captures what follows the last.