# Find and trim part of what is found using regular expression

Tags: regex, unix

I'm a newbie in writing regular expressions

I have a file name like this **TST0101201304-123.txt** and my target is to get the numbers between **'-'** and **'.txt'**

So I wrote this formula `-([0-9]*)\.txt` this will get me the numbers that I want, but in addition, it is retrieving the highfin **'-'** and the last part of the string also **'.txt'** so the result in the example above is **'-123.txt'**

So my question is:

**Is there a way in regular expressions to get only part of the matched string, like a submatch of the match without the need to trim it in my shell script code for unix?**

I found this answer but it is getting the same result:
[Regexp: Trim parts of a string and return what ever is left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996078/regexp-trim-parts-of-a-string-and-return-what-ever-is-left)

*Tip: To test my regular expressions is used [this](http://regexpal.com/) website*

Comment: Your number is captured by the parenthesis `()`. You can usually retrieve it in your API/tool in some way, but that depends on what you are using. Some times it's accessed via `$1`.

Comment: The regex as a whole matches `-123.txt`, but the captured (remembered) substring matches the part you want, the `123`.  Make sure you use the capture and not the whole match.

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Comment: No, unix command, I'm also a newbie in unix, this is the command that i need to use there `expr match "$stringZ" '-([0-9]*)\.txt'`

Comment: @simsim: I'm confused. At least on my system, `expr match TST0101201304-123.txt '-([0-9]*)\.txt'` does not print what you say it does.

Comment: @ruakh, I'm also confused of unix, I've been working on it since 3 days only, take it easy on me :D

Comment: By the way -- the reason that go-oleg asked "Are you using javascript?" is that you tested your regex by using a tester for JavaScript regexes. The regexes supported by `expr match` are quite different, so naturally regexpal has limited usefulness for them.

Comment: So, you are saying that the syntax of regular expression formula is different ?
I use the same regex in .net/javascript/ and java they work without modifications in the expression usually

Comment: @simsim: .Net, JavaScript, and Java regular expressions are all quite similar in basic features (though there are a number of differences in more advanced features); but the regex notation supported by `expr match` has a lot of differences even in very basic features, e.g., using `\(...\)` for capture-groups rather than `(...)`.

Comment: @ruakh, thanks, I discovered that the hard way, testing millions of codes and following tutorials. Eventually I used substring command after getting the positions of the '-' character and so on, long workaround.
So, if you would like to post your comments summary as an answer to give you some votes ;) they were helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different regex-engines are different. Since you're using `expr match`, you need to make two changes:

- `expr match` expects a regex that matches the *entire* string; so, you need to add `.*` at the beginning of yours, to cover everything before the hyphen.
- `expr match` uses [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BREs)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html), which use `\(` and `\)` for grouping (and capturing) rather than merely `(` and `)`.

But, conveniently, when you give `expr match` a regex that contains a capture-group, its output is the content of that capture-group; you don't need to do anything else special. So:

```
$ expr match TST0101201304-123.txt '.*-\([0-9]*\)\.txt'
123
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, and it is very useful for future references

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookbehind and lookahead

```
(?<=-)[0-9]*(?=[.]txt)
```

Don't know if it would work in unix

Answer (score 1):

sed is your friend.

```
echo filename | sed -e 's/-\([0-9]*\)/\1'
```

should get you what you want.